# Total Number of days hours and minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for how many days hours and minutes elapse between today and 27/08/2020 17:00.

Is there and formula where i can achieve this?

The output should look like this:

```
0 Year, 1 Month, 7 Weeks, 50 Days, 1,207, Hours, 72,427 Minutes, and 4,345,620 Seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of formulas that can help you here, here's how I would handle that.

Put your date in cell A1.

For years enter this formula in any cell:

`=DATEDIF($A$1,TODAY(),"Y")`

For months use the years formula, but change the "Y" to "M".

For days use:
`=DAYS(TODAY(),A1)`

For hours use:
`=ROUNDDOWN((NOW()-A1)*24,0)`

For minutes use:
`=ROUNDDOWN((NOW()-A1)*24*60,0)`

For seconds use:
`=ROUNDDOWN((NOW()-A1)*24*60*60,0)`

Applying the formatting you want will add a lot of length, put this formula in any cell:

`=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")&" Years, "&TEXT(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"M"),"#,###")&" Months, "&TEXT(DAYS(TODAY(),A1),"#,###")&" Days, "&TEXT(ROUNDDOWN((NOW()-A1)*24,0),"#,###")&" Hours, "&TEXT(ROUNDDOWN((NOW()-A1)*24*60,0),"#,###")&" Minutes, and "&TEXT(ROUNDDOWN((NOW()-A1)*24*60*60,0),"#,###")&" Seconds"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
=NOW()-DATEVALUE("08/27/2020")+17/24
```

in the cell you want, and then just format that cell using custom formatting like this:

```
yy "years" mm "months" dd "days" hh "hours" mm "minutes"
```

You'd need to either refresh that cell regularly, or you can use the Application.OnTime command in a macro to have it recalculate for you.

Comment: this will not work, as `dd` will only go to 31 and then 28 then 31 it will never reach 50.  Same with `hh` it will be part of the day same with `mm`